# Does analytical solution exist?

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a function:

$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{a_i^3}{(1 + xa_i)^3}$

where $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are arbitrary constants.

I'd like to find the root of the function $f(x)$. That is, find $x$ where $f(x) = 0$. This is straightforward to solve numerically (I use the Newton method). Does an analytical solution exist for this? I anticipate the answer is "No", but would like a confirmation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's equivalent to solving a $(3N-3)$th degree polynomial equation so no for all $N>2$

Comment: Ok, thanks Winther.

Comment: It is not a general polinomial of degree (3N-3). There might exist a solution. People usually throw this result incorrectly. For instance the polynomial $x^6+7$ is of degree six and its roots can be compute analytically. The argument above is not sufficient